# Custom SVG icon ionic 3 tabs, icon has background color

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I make a custom SVG icon on ionic 3 tabs, evrthing works well in browser,
but when I tested it on a device or emulator the color become wrong on the background

How to fix this?

```css
ion-icon {
    &[class*="custom-"] {
        mask-size: contain;
        mask-position: 50% 50%;
        mask-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: currentColor;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
    }
    &[class*="custom-donkey"] {
        mask-image: url(../assets/icon/donkey.svg);
    }
    &[class*="custom-cat-ol"] {
        mask-image: url(../assets/icon/cat-outline.svg);
    }
}
```

[image: pict works on web]

[image: pict wrong collor on emulator]

Please help I thing from this code

```css
background: currentColor;
```

Comment: Why do you not hard code the color, if you want it to be a specific one?

Comment: no i didnt want a spesific color, the problem is when i us custom icon, its become like picture above,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
&[class*="custom-donkey"] {
        mask-image: url(../assets/icon/donkey.svg);
    }
    &[class*="custom-cat-ol"] {
        mask-image: url(../assets/icon/cat-outline.svg);
    }
```

instead of Adding The Url/Path of the SVG icon Try to add the SVG Code or You can Directly add the SVG code in bottom menu in HTML and Adjust the Size using **CSS** Class